# SignIn Authentication with Firebase issue

Tags: javascript, firebase-authentication

The try and catch method is not verifying if the email and password the user entering exists in the firebase, but it shows an error message on the console.

```
function login(email, password) {
    return auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);
}
const handleLogin = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    try {
        setError("")
        login(emailRef.current.value, passwordRef.current.value);      
    } catch {
        setError("The email or password you entered is incorrect");
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the error on the console?

Comment: "There is no user record corresponding to this identifier. The user may have been deleted."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The call to `signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)` is an asynchronous call and returns a promise.

A promise is essentially an asynchronous task that will either complete or fail. Read more about promises here [Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise).

In this scenario, the function must contact the Firebase auth servers, attempt to fetch the user account, and then return either an error or sign the user into their account.

Why isn't it showing the error? Well, your function is finishing its execution before it has received a response from the server. If there is no response, then it doesn't know that there is an error. In order to fix this,
you must wait for the promise to resolve. To do so, I recommend using the async/await syntax.

Modify your function to be like so:

```
 const handleLogin = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    try {
        setError("")
        await login(emailRef.current.value, passwordRef.current.value);      
    }catch {
        setError("The email or password you entered is incorrect");
    }
}
```